# Jenkins matrix project combination filter - how to configure the groovy expression?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have  a Jenkins multi configuration project with two axis:

1. `sbBrowser` with values:

   ```
   firefox
   ie
   chrome
   ```
2. `envConfig` with values:

   ```
   pp1
   pp2
   pp3
   staging
   systemtest
   ```

I have to create combination filter to run only with `sbBrowser = firefox` on all of the `envConfig`.

How to build the expression?

Something like:

```
sbBrowser=="firefox" && envConfig=="pp1" "pp2" "pp3" "staging" "systemtest"
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok, the following expression is working as a charm:

```
(sbBrowser=="firefox")  && (envConfig=="pp1") ||(sbBrowser=="firefox")  && (envConfig=="pp2")||(sbBrowser=="firefox")  && (envConfig=="pp3")||(sbBrowser=="firefox")  && (envConfig=="staging")||(sbBrowser=="firefox")  && (envConfig=="systemtest")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to run only for firefox, on all values of envConfig, then why specify members of the envConfig set? Just do `(sbBrowser=="firefox")` and it will run only on Firefox, for all members of envConfig.

Comment: Definitely the better answer here.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way either-

```
(sbBrowser=="firefox") && ["pp1","pp2","pp3","staging","systemtest"].contains(envConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the groovy expression is defined in other build parameter, for example, when using [Matrix Combinations Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/matrix+combinations+plugin) that defines a default combination - then the parameter name should be inside `evaluate()`:

[image: Matrix Combinations Parameter]

...

[image]

You'll also have to approve the use of

> method groovy.lang.Script evaluate java.lang.String

under ***Manage Jenkins*** --> ***In-process Script Approval***