# Jenkins combination filter with Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins multi configuration project with two variables to combine:

1. version (from build matrix axis)

   ```
   1.2
   1.3
   ```
2. platform (build parameter)

   ```
   ubuntu
   windows
   ```

Some combinations are supported, others not. There are many more than above but trying to keep it simple here.

I have tried combination filters such as:

```
    (platform == "windows" && version == "1.1") || (platform == "windows" && version == "1.2") ...
```

But with many combinations these get very long and complicated. I would like to be able to just read the list of allowed platforms per version from a file. The filter would then be a simple map-style lookup based on the file contents. Like "return versions[version].contains(platform)".

I considered having a one-line combination filter to read a file as Groovy script and execute it. Couldn't figure out that one-liner.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232314/jenkins-matrix-project-combination-filter-how-to-configure-the-groovy-expressi) answer suggested putting in "evaluate(paramName)" as a filter. Put the more complex Groovy script into that "paramName" and use it to read the mapping file etc. I don't know how where I can insert such as parameter to evaluate.

The [Groovy Execution Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Groovy+Execution+Strategy+Plugin) seems like it might work. But I am not quite sure how to script it with this one either. How do I combine  my variables and with a mapping file in this plugin and what to return?

Ultimately, I would prefer to be able to use the default combination filter support, so I could also re-use it in the [Matrix Combinations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/matrix+combinations+plugin) as a shortcut selection (it supports combination filter).

So prefer the plain combination filter but if must can use other approaches. Goal is to filter allowed combinations.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not to use a json file to store config and simple code to validate your platform:version pair against it?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I implemented reading platform:version from json using the Groovy Execution Strategy Plugin. It works otherwise but the job hangs if one of the nodes with a required label is offline. See my new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362161/jenkins-matrix-groovy-execution-strategy-plugin-hangs-if-label-is-offline