# Jenkins Matrix Groovy Execution Strategy Plugin hangs if label is offline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to implement a more complex combination filter for Jenkins using the [Matrix Groovy Execution Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Groovy+Execution+Strategy+Plugin). See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349595/jenkins-combination-filter-with-groovy-script) for more details. It seems to work otherwise but if the nodes where the label is set are offline, the matrix job hangs and does not put the rest of the matrix items into the job queue.

This is enough Groovy to cause the same effect in the plugin:

```
combinations.each{
            result[it.cfg] = result[it.cfg] ?: []
            result[it.cfg] << it
}
return [result, true]
```

If I set the execution strategy to "Classic", all the job labels go into the queue even if some nodes are offline. I have "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" enabled if that makes any difference.

Is there some setting I need to fix or is this a plugin issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the classic strategy puts all the keystone jobs in the queue and then the others afterwards.

This plugin will schedule them in sections and if the node is offline then they will wait, which is standard behaviour

you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891709/jenkins-skip-if-node-is-offline)

Note: I wrote the matrix execution strategy plugin

---

Incorporated comments

You can force all the combinations to submit in one go by doing the following:

```
combinations.each{
            result["a"] = result["a"] ?: []
            result["a"] << it
}
return [result, true]
```

Comment: Thanks for the plugin and the info :). Your linked answer does not quite work for me since our systems schedules a number of jobs for labels that are all offline. These trigger a VM instance to be spawned with the label. So I need all the labels to go into queue so the system will spawn the VM's for them. Can I modify the plugin somehow or is the other way to get them all in queue?

Comment: You can add them all into `result["a"]` then they would all get queued together. There is logic to submit them in batches as per the hash key

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work. Is there some variable I can query to replace "a" with the job name?

Comment: Its only used to segregate the sections to run, other than that it has no use. So anything will work

Comment: I was just looking for the finishing touch for the log file. I accepted your answer, maybe you can update it with the information from the comments as well? Might be helpful for the generations to come.. :)